# Riemann integration Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Is there any (measure theoretic) explanation that why do we get some positive valued answer with the help of Riemann integration . Since the length of each subinterval is tending to zero and since the rational numbers form a set of measure zero the positive valued answer of the Riemann integral we get is due to the irrational numbers is there any explanation about why is this happening?

Comment: The length of the intervals tends to zero, but the intervals keep having a positive length. It is like in the sum $1+1/2+1/4+1/8+\cdots=2$ , where $2$ is never reached by a partial sum although the sum is exactly $2$.

Comment: length of subintervals tends to 0,but the number of intervals goes to infinity. So if you're integrating a positive, (say continuous) function on a non-trivial interval, you'll get a positive number in the end